# 'waiting time' for a drupal page taken is more thats why the drupal page is slow

Tags: php, performance, drupal, drupal-7

'waiting time' for a drupal page taken is more thats why the drupal page is slow

There is one page in my drupal site, which loads in 23sec this is too much and the page is of 1.8MB.

Upon checking why its slow, it seems the 'waiting' time taken is large like 19 secs.

Checked this with 'NET' firebug plugin.

Also i checked disabling custom modules and checking queries execution time.

Thing to note is its 'https://' page.

Can it be a server problem?

Tried boost module but it doesn't cache https:// pages.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First thing I would do is switch the sites theme to the standard drupal theme, it will break bits of your site momentarily but it will give you an indication if the issue is in the site current theme.
Then would use console in chrome to see some hints. Mainly look at the network tab and compare it with regular pages. It could also be a JS function timing out or taking forever.

Finally if you think it's your server then I would install a program called htop. this will monitor your servers performance. Also try setting the site up locally to recreate the error.

Are there any over complex views on the page? If so, try disabling these to find the culprit.

Comment: disabled all the views for that page, still no change. Will try out server performance checking.

Comment: Try also deactivating suspicious modules, specially yours.